# Rails routes constraints issue/bug or feature?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-routing

I had raised this routing issue on GitHub but found no takers there, so reaching out to the crowd here.

Basically the issue relates to when a `constraints:` on a particular route is used within the context of a higher order `constraints:`.

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/35295

Comment: I guess this one can be closed?

Comment: @DennyMueller closed? but no one has answered yet?

Answer (score 1):

*Inner constraints overwrite outer constraints.*

There are a couple of github issues about that, e.g. https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/19075#issuecomment-92028613

So your `constraints: ->(request) { request.format.html? }` "disables" the `constraints subdomain: 'admin'` So all requests go directly to the first `get '*path', to: 'home#show'` that matches.

You can easily test this just change the order of both and you will always end up in `App::HomeController#show`.

If you remove `constraints: ->(request) { request.format.html? }` then the request ends up in the correct controller but then loses the forced html.
For having both constraints you could try something along those lines. Use constraint modules as described [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints).

```
module CustomAdminConstraint
  def self.matches? request
    request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain == 'admin' && request.format.html?
    # possible short form
    # request.subdomain&.== 'admin' && request.format.html?
  end
end

module CustomAppConstraint
  def self.matches? request
    request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain == 'app' && request.format.html?
  end
end

# routes.rb
constraints CustomAdminConstraint do
  namespace :admin, path: nil do
    get '*path', to: 'home#show'
  end
end

constraints CustomAppConstraintdo
  namespace :app, path: nil do
    get '*path', to: 'home#show'
  end
end
```

But be aware that future other formats are trickier to implement. Phew... what a ride

Comment: We serve some API/JSON requests from the `admin` subdomain as well so thats why checking for `.html?` in a constraint module wont work for us.

Comment: Then remove the outer constraint completely and build multiple constraints modules and add  them directly to the paths. Like `AdminJsonConstraint`, `AdminHtmlConstraint` and so on. Or if you want to keep the outer constraint you can make 2 constraint blocks for Admin. One that is for json and one for html.

Comment: Interesting, I did not think about adding a AdminHtmlConstraint module inside a parent AdminConstraint module. Let me try that, thanks.

Comment: @kapso Well if you do it that what you will overwrite you outer constraint again. Same issue as from the beginning. This rule always applies: `Inner constraints overwrite outer constraints`. You can either make couple of outer constraints for admin(html/json) / app(html/json). or make just constraints for each path definition.